# Telerik MVC custom AJAX editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the `MVC version of the Telerik controls` with `ASP.NET MVC` and the `razor view engine`.  I have an AJAX grid.  When I click edit I want it to display the data in form style.  But the issue is that I want to rearrange the in form controls they way that I want them to display.  How would I do something like that?  Currently the controls are all beneath each other.  I want to create my own layout for editing.

I have a whole lot of other controls on the view, one of them being this grid.  My view model object has a list of Children objects and I want to use my grid to populate this list.

The view model for my view:

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   // Other properties

   // I want this to be populated from the grid
   public IEnumerable<Children> Children { get; set; }
}
```

My grid's code for the Children list:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Children)
   .Name("grdChildren")
   .Columns(column =>
      {
         column.Bound(x => x.Id);
         column.Bound(x => x.FullName);
      }
   )
   .DataKeys(keys =>
      {
         keys.Add(x => x.Id);
      }
   )
   .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
      {
         dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Grid")
            .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Grid")
            .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Grid")
            .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Grid");
      }
   )
   .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text))
   .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InForm))
)
```

I'm not sure how my editor template must look like?  What must it extend?  And I can't get it to show in the inline form.  I worked through the sample from Brad Wilson but I am not getting it.  Can someone please explain what is happening?

Just another questions..  On my other page I have a grid with other HTML controls on the page.  If I am busy editing data in the grid, and click insert, how would I prevent the other controls on the page not to be validated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom editor template for your model and arrange the fields as you wish. [This](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor-form.aspx) code library project shows how.

Comment: Thanks so far.  I see that there is an .ascx file.  Where is that used in the Index page where the grid is?  I can't figure this part out?

Comment: This is how ASP.NET MVC editor templates work. Check this blog post for a more in-depth explanation of this feature: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Comment: You need to create an ASP.NET MVC editor template for your model. Once it works with Html.EditorForModel it will work with the grid. Experiment with the code library - check ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates. I don't know how to help further.

Comment: It works like magic. If your model is called "Customer" then you need to create a partial view called Customer.cshtml and put it in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates. ASP.NET MVC will pick that up when Html.EditorForModel is used.

Comment: Thanks.  But what if I don't want to use EditorFor?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean that you don't want to use EditorFor? What else do you want to use?

Comment: This is not going to work.  I still don't think you understand my situation.  I have a view model called EditGrantApplicationViewModel, and in the view model I have a customer list which I want displayed in the grid (there are other controls also on the page like textboxes).  So in my Cusotmer.cshtml file, how would I specify this model?  This won't work @model MyProject.ViewModels.EditGrantApplicationViewModel.Cusotmer

Comment: There is a HUGE communication gap here.  I want to specify my own textboxes like I do @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployeeNumber, new { maxlength = "6", size = "6" })

Comment: Can you maybe compile me a solution given my situation?  Can I get your email address so that we can take this offline?

Comment: No, I am afraid I can't do this. I already provided a working project showing how to customize the edit form of the grid. I cannot give you my email address nor can I prepare a sample project based on your requirement. I don't think stackoverflow is meant for this kind of support.

Comment: Should we take it over to the Telerik forums?  They normally exchange code there.  Your sample does not cater for what I am trying to do.  And I don't know why Telerik is making this so hard!

Comment: The question says "Telerik MVC custom AJAX editor template" and the linked code library project shows exactly that. Please use the sample project as a start and try to customize it. Of course it is not 100% the same thing as you need but you cannot expect us to have any possible project implemented as a sample.