# Editor template for Telerik MVC grid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Telerik MVC custom AJAX editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270856/telerik-mvc-custom-ajax-editor-template)

I am using the MVC Telerik controls with the ASP.NET MVC 3 razor view engine. I am struggling with the grid. I initially posted a question but did not find any luck with it. It is here:

[Telerik MVC custom AJAX editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270856/telerik-mvc-custom-ajax-editor-template)

My view accepts a view model called `EditGrantApplicationViewModel`. This view has many different types of controls on it. Textboxes, dropdowns and a Telerik grid. The system is an education fund system, and while applying for the loan you have to specify your children's details. So I thought it would be better for the user if I display the children in a grid and then a child can be added via the grid and linked to the Children propery in my view model.

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Children> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I bound the grid to the Children property of the view model like such:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Children)
   .Name("grdChildren")
   .Columns(column =>
   {
      column.Bound(x => x.Id);
      column.Bound(x => x.FullName);
   })
   .DataKeys(keys =>
   {
      keys.Add(x => x.Id);
   })
   .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
   {
      dataBinding.Ajax()
         .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Grid")
         .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Grid")
         .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Grid")
         .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Grid");
   })
   .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text))
   .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InForm))
)
```

There reason why I chose an AJAX grid is because when I click insert in the grid then the whole page gets validated. I don't want to add the children to the database here, I just want to add to the Children property.

The issue that I am having is with the editor template. I'm doing inline editing and I want to specify my own editor template because I want to rearrange my controls in this template. How would I create an editor template for `EditGrantApplicationViewModel.Children`?

I create a partial view called `Children.cshtml` but it is not being pulled into my grid. I was told to have it use use the Children model, but how would I specify this in the partial view as I can't have something like:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.EditGrantApplicationViewModel.Children
```

I got an example but I can't get it to work in my scenario.

Am I doing this the right way? What else can be tried?

Comment: It's my question that I am trying to get an answer for. Read my post then you will see that I mentioned it!!  Don't vote this closed please.  I am in search of an answer which I did not get in the other post.

Comment: I've searched high and low for an answer and not able to get something for my scenario.

Comment: It isn't a dupe, folks.  Move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.

The Children property in my view model is a list of Children objects.  I created a partial view in `/Shared/Editor/Templates` called `Children.cshtml`.

I thought that Children.cshtml should receive the model as such:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.EditGrantApplicationViewModel.Children
```

which is the property that I specified in `@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Children)` but it should receive the model object that the list is made up of, name the Children object:

@model MyProject.DomainObjects.Children

And now it is being pulled through :)